# No more OS detected but disk is good and os still here

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I had a weird issue with my HP laptop this morning. It suddently shut down and when I restarted it, it was in some kind of manufacture mode. I managed to get it back to normal boot mode by following official HP informations [here](https://h20565.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?sp4ts.oid=5045209&docId=emr_na-c02912206&docLocale=en_US) but now when I boot, it doesn't find any OS anymore. I checked the harddrive with the HP hardware full check and it seems fine.

I then booted on an old Fedora 21 live usb I have. All my partitions are still here and seems functionnal. I had a multiboot in efi with a grub. I had a Windows and 3 unix on my drive. Everything seems to be still here.

How can I manage to get my grub and all os back without losing everything? Also, before doing anything "dangerous" I would like to make a full save of my disk just in case, how could I perform that?

Comment: Use your live USB to reinstall grub following the directions [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found what was wrong finally, my bios reseted itself to default configuration. I had to set the UEFI mod in legacy again and my grub showed up.